# Swift "error: in auto-import: failed to get module 'foo' from AST context:"

Tags: swift, debugging, swift3, llvm, lldb

With the following setup ([gist](https://gist.github.com/emlai/cf629399b89bec5a60f7e72ec2e08073)):

**Package.swift:**

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "foo",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/rxwei/LLVM_C", majorVersion: 1, minor: 0)
    ]
)
```

**Makefile:**

```
all:
    @swift build \
        -Xcc -I`llvm-config --includedir` \
        -Xlinker -L`llvm-config --libdir` \
        -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker `llvm-config --libdir`
```

**main.swift:**

```
import LLVM_C.Core

func foo(_ a: Int) {
    let b = a * a
    print(b)
}

foo(4)
```

After compiling an executable with `make` and starting the executable in a debugger, I cannot print the values of any variables:

```
(lldb) b foo
Breakpoint 1: where = foo`foo.foo (Swift.Int) -> () + 12 at main.swift:4, address = 0x00000001000014dc
(lldb) r
Process 14376 launched: '/Users/emlai/Code/foo/.build/debug/foo' (x86_64)
Process 14376 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x226d5, 0x00000001000014dc foo`foo(a=4) -> () + 12 at main.swift:4, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x00000001000014dc foo`foo(a=4) -> () + 12 at main.swift:4
   1    import LLVM_C.Core
   2    
   3    func foo(_ a: Int) {
-> 4        let b = a * a
   5        print(b)
   6    }
   7    
(lldb) p a
error: in auto-import:
failed to get module 'foo' from AST context:

(lldb) p a
Shared Swift state for foo has developed fatal errors and is being discarded.
REPL definitions and persistent names/types will be lost.
warning: Swift error in module foo.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

error: in auto-import:
failed to get module 'foo' from AST context
```

If I comment out the `import LLVM_C.Core` line, everything works properly.

This is preventing me from debugging my project and making forward progress. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Searching the web for this problem results only to "its a lldb bug".
The only way I've found to debug is to debug tests. But AFAIK you can't run tests with having own `main.swift` script. This results into `multiple definition of 'main'`.

So just follow instructions here https://swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-package-manager to create needed file hierarchy for package with tests (with `swift package init` or manually), write some tests, run `swift test` and, finally, `lldb .build/debug/fooPackageTests.xctest` (`<binary name>PackageTests.xctest` is binary file for running tests). I suppose it is compiled differently in some point rather than common binary. At least that worked in my case :)

Good luck with debugging! :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try clean and build project in xcode